# Why am I running into org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec error?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I have the following simple pom.xml. When I run the application it runs into following error, I read many answers for this problem but they did not work out.

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource resource = client.resource("Query Request Goes Here");
    List<Output> allOutputs = resource.get(new GenericType<List<Output>>(){});
    System.out.println(allOutputs.size());



Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project eBaytest: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eBaytest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do as it says and run with -X option.  Then provide the output here.

Comment: The error message seeme to me to give the right hint: `Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 `?

Comment: This can't be your whole pom, or else it would say that exec-maven-plugin is missing. Please provide more info, like the whole pom, some source code, the whole maven command and most of all: the output of appending -e to the mvn command. Were you following the Jersey getting started guide?

Comment: I am not sure where I can type the maven command on Netbeans

Comment: @J888 - Type it at the Linux / Windows command line.  And if you don't have a free-standing Maven installation on your dev machine, install one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to set up a new Jersey project using Jersey 1.x. My first recommendation would be to use the latest 2.5.1. Also, you'll definitely want to be able to run Maven from the command line, so install that first. When you have that, follow [these instructions](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) to set up a new Jersey project, basically:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1
```

After that, make your changes and run:

```
mvn -e compile exec:java
```

If you get any errors then, you can come back here and share them with us.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying create new model table, and by mistake add two @id column tag sometime this error occurs, check the model class and delete unnecessary one the problem will disappear.